# How do I correctly pronounce "sóncræft"

Tags: pronunciation

How do I correctly pronounce the Anglo Saxon word sóncræft (music)?

I feel it should be "sonn crayfte" or "sonn creft".

Comment: Since *ay* [wasn't a vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology#Vowels) in Old English, your feeling is probably wrong.

Comment: Pronounce it as its spelling suggests, [so:nkræft] in IPA. Old English (Anglo-Saxon) spelling usually represents the pronunciation pretty well; English spelling didn't get funky until much later on.

Answer (score 1):

Old English pronunciation is something of a mystery; what we do know is largely informed guess-work.  I will, however, describe what I can.

The accent signifies a long vowel; in this case, pronounce it by elongating the *o* sound.

Pronounce the *r* by flicking your tongue once off the roof of your mouth.  Your tongue will lightly tap the place where you press your tongue to pronounce *l* sounds.  This is done similarly in Italian, Spanish, and Classical Latin pronunciation.

Pronounce the *æ* how you pronounce the *a* in *cat*, but never how you pronounce the *a* in *father*.  It is somewhere between the *a* in *father* and the *e* in *bet*, which is why the Anglo-Saxons used the *æ* (a + e) to represent it.

The rest of the word is pronounced as in Modern English.

If anything is unclear, leave a comment and I will elaborate.

EDIT:

I forgot to say that the stress almost always goes on the first syllable of any word.

I decided that it would be easiest for me to record the word and upload it.  Note that I am sick at the moment and my pronunciation will not be flawless, but it will give you the general idea.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73358677/soncraeft.wav

As Peter Shor pointed out, we do not truly know how the Anglo-Saxon *r* sounded.  I find that the trilled *r* fits better with the rest of the pronunciation, but, if you find it difficult, then go with whatever you think best.

Comment: I don't think anybody really knows how the consonant *r* sounded in Old English, so if that pronunciation is hard for you, pronounce the *r* however you like.

Comment: Ok, so we're thinking "sohn krafft" with the r said in any way I like?